# Putting initialization task into background in Flask app

Tags: python, flask, parallel-processing, background

I am working on a data science project in which I need to train a machine learning model and provide an API for accessing the model's predictions on test data.

I have everything running so far, using Flask to serve a HTML page containing the models prediction on the test data that is passed to it. I would like this to start up more nicely. Training the model takes a significant amount of time, and the Flask app is only started afterwards, which means that my API cannot be accessed until the model is trained. The startup sequence up until now is as follows:

```
Read training database
Train model
Start Flask app
```

I would like to change this order to

```
Start Flask app
Read training database
Train model
```

Then, when I access `localhost/?input=<xxx>` before the model is trained, I would like to display a message like "Model is being trained".

I think I will need some kind of parallel processing scheme, I have looked at the multiprocessing module, but I'm not sure about the best way to do this. In particular, how to I get (a reference to) the trained `model` back from the background process? And when is the correct place to call `p.join()` given my code is structured like this:

```py
import flask
from multiprocessing import Process
...

def get_trained_model():
    model = expensiveComputation()
    return model # I don't thing "return" is the right way to go??

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=get_trained_model)
    p.start()

    app = flask.Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
    def home():
        if some_flag_that_model_ready:
            model = somehow_get_model_from_process()
            model_response = model.predict(method_to_get_test_data()).toString()
            return model_response
        else:
            return "model is still being trained"

    app.run()
```

Can this be done in a simple manner, without using external tools like RQ or Celery? Is this the right approach?